# How do I use node.js http-proxy for logging HTTP traffic in a computer?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I am trying to implement the simplest example:

```
var http = require('http'),
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
    //
    // I would add logging here
    //
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, { host: 'www.google.com', port: 80 });
}).listen(18000);
```

When I configure my browser to use this proxy and I navigate to www.google.com I receive no response. What is that I am doing wrong?

I'm using Windows 7 Chrome

Comment: Can you specify what OS and what browser?  Each handles proxies differently.

Comment: Is this working for you with the latest changes in the library?

Seems like now it is mandatory to pass the `target` field in the options otherwise just simply running the above code gives me `Must provide valid URL for target`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an simple example how to log requests.
I use a similar to log all my domains to one database.

I copied much from [http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-middlewares](https://web.archive.org/web/20120509175116/http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-middlewares) (archived)

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
        
logger = function() {    
  // This will only run once
  var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./requests.log');

  return function (request, response, next) { 
    // This will run on each request.
    logFile.write(JSON.stringify(request.headers, true, 2));
    next();
  }
}

httpProxy.createServer(
  logger(), // <-- Here is all the magic
  {
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
      'example1.com': '127.0.0.1:8001', // server on localhost:8001
      'example2.com': '127.0.0.1:8002'  // server 2 on localhost:8002
  }
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Should this still be working? I'm trying to log the requests when I access different urls but can't figure it out...

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as now it is mandatory to pass some kind of a target or a forward field in the options. Running the above code gives me Must provide valid url for Target.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps because the posted information are really short.
But I found a post that they updated the api ...

you might want to check out this post:

Updating to node-http-proxy v0.5.0
http://blog.nodejitsu.com/updating-node-http-proxy

Comment: Wayback archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160310162833/http://blog.nodejitsu.com/updating-node-http-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

I done like logging the request headers object on the event `proxyReq`

```
const http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    fs = require('fs');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

const logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./requests.log');

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    //Log incoming request headers
    logFile.write(JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
});

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        changeOrigin: true,
        target: 'example1.com'
    });
});

console.log("listening on port 5050")
server.listen(5050);
```