# how to get a Network Panel show up when debugging Electron/Node applications

Tags: node.js, http, request, electron

I am building an electron application and I am using libraries (request/axios) for making requests. One thing I didn't expect is that making these requests on Node won't display a `Network Panel` when running in chrome debug mode. Is there a simple way to tell debug mode to turn on a network panel for tuning into `https` requests(I assume these libraries all use https)?

---

currently on my server side electron app i only see the following
[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot as well to explain your problem please

Comment: @TarunLalwani I think that's already been provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to monitor the network on node.js similar to chrome/firefox developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873332/how-to-monitor-the-network-on-node-js-similar-to-chrome-firefox-developer-tools)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1 - create your own

you can wrap your `axios` functions and send an event to your renderer process

### main electron process

```
const electron = require('electron');

const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = electron;

const _axios = require('request-promise');

const axios = {
  get: (url, params) => _axios.get(url, params).then(sendData),
  post: (url, params) => _axios.post(url, params).then(sendData),
  delete: (url, params) => _axios.delete(url, params).then(sendData),
  put: (url, params) => _axios.put(url, params).then(sendData)
  // ...
};

function sendData() {
  return (data) => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('network', data);
    return data;
  };
}
```

### renderer process (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css"

        rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .kb-debug-widget {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background: grey;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="kb-debug-widget">
    <table class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth"
           id="network">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Body</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    require('./renderer.js');
    var {
      ipcRenderer,
      remote
    } = require('electron');

    ipcRenderer.on('network', (event, response) => {
      const networkElement = document.getElementById('network');

      // print whatever you want here!
      networkElement.innerHTML +=
        `
      <tr>
        <td>${response.request.href}</td>
        <td>${response.request.method}</td>
        <td>${response.statusCode}</td>
        <td>${response.headers['content-type']}</td>
        <td>${response. data}</td>
      </tr>
      `;

      // you can also print the network requests to the console with a decent UI by using console.table:
      console.table({
        name: response.request.href,
        method: response.request.method,
        status: response.statusCode,
        type: response.headers['content-type'],
        body: response. data,
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This will create a widget on the bottom of your view.

it's even easier with `request`:

```
const _request = require('request-promise');
const _axios = require('request-promise');

// this should cover all sub-methods
const request = (params, callback) => {
  return _request(params, callback)
  .on('response', (response) => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('network', response);
    return response;
  });
};
```

Since both `axios` & `request` return similar objects, you can use the same function on the renderer side.

### code in action

[image]

[Here's a GitHub repository with the code implemented](https://github.com/Thatkookooguy/SO-question-electron)

## Solution 1: Alt - write network requests to renderer's console

I also added an option to print the requests to the dev tools console, with `console.table`. Here's how it looks:
[image]
You can leave only this method if you don't want a widget inside your HTML.

## Solution 2 - Run electron with the `--inspect` flag

You can also just [run electron with the `inspect` flag](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process#command-line-switches), which allows you to debug your server code and has its own network tab with the "server-side" HTTP requests.

In order to see it, run your electron application like so:

```
electron --inspect=<port> your/app
```

if you want to immediatly break on the first line, run the same command but replace `--inspect` with `--inspect-brk`.

After running the command, open any web-browser and go to `chrome://inspect` and selecting to inspect the launched Electron app present there.
[image]

Comment: how can i open the network tab for the server code when running with the --inspect flag?

Comment: @user2167582 added some info to my answer on the `--inspect` flag.

Comment: Thatkookooguy hmm all I see on the page is this `WebSockets request was expected`

Comment: @user2167582 not sure if that is what happening with your set-up, but that error is usually shown if the port you pass to `--inspect` is already in use by another server. try either not passing anything to use the default port (The default `port` is `5858`), or change the debug port to another port and try again. This feature uses `node.js` debugger protocol, so if you can run a simple node application with `node --inspect index.js` and see the debugger, it should work with electron as well.

Comment: @user2167582 also, I made a mistake on the how to launch that option in my answer. fixed, so you might just want to retry that again with the new instructions I wrote

Comment: @user2167582 tl;dr : instead of writing `localhost:<port>` in your web browser, open chrome, and paste in the address bar: `chrome://inspect`. Then, select the launched Electron app present there.

Comment: i tried that also, with that approach i don't get a `Network` tab. do i need to call .send('network') from ipcMain?

Comment: @user2167582 the two solution aren't related. `ipcMain` is used to create a network tab in the `HTML` of your renderer process. `--inspect` is used to debug using node's V8 debug protocol. Those are two different methods of doing the same thing.

did you try the method with the HTML? that might work (it's the first solution I wrote in my answer)

Comment: how? i'm in the main application, here there aren't any html factor.

Comment: `ipcMain` allows you to communicate between the **main application** and the **renderer**. in the first solution I suggested, there's a **main application code snippet**, and a **renderer code snippet**. Those snippets communicate with one another and that way you can create your own network tab inside the electron's app HTML.
[here's a GitHub repo with the electron app I created](https://github.com/Thatkookooguy/SO-question-electron) to test the 1st solution. maybe that will help you understand it better

Comment: I see what you are saying, so this is a work around to get electron to pipe its output to the browserWindow so it can render these network requests in its devtool.

Comment: Yes. I wrote two options: in both I pipe the network requests to the browser window. In one, I print the events to the console.log, and in the other, I create an html widget and show the requests there

Comment: I am getting a IncomingMessage {_readableState: ReadableState, readable: true in the response, and im pipiing that to the mainwindow, but nothing is displaying in the network tab. Your other solution sounds great and I'll give the bounty but it would be nice if you can help me how to get the request into the network panel.

Comment: @user2167582 sure. contact me by email and I'll try and help. thatkookooguy@kibibit.io

Comment: is that the type for `reponse` that you would expect? `IncomingMessage`?

Comment: @user2167582 I'm not sure. are you talking about the first or second parameter in the event callback? the first parameter is the event. and it might be an `IncomingMessage`. The second parameter is the data you send with that event.

Comment: send me an email and I'll continue to help there.

The comments section shouldn't be that long of a discussion

Comment: I'd like to use Solution 2 but for me there is no Network tab when launched via --inspect-brk

Comment: I dont have the network panel in the inspector. Please enlight me. using electron-webpack

Comment: @Sw0ut You need [an external debugger](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process#external-debuggers). If you are using vscode, you can read on [how to use debugging with vscode](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process-vscode)

Comment: @ShaneGannon @Sw0ut I figured it out. The `--inspect` flag is only for the `Node.js` portion of Electron.  If you want the frontend portion too, do `--inspect=9229 --remote-debugging-port=9222`.  Then in `chrome://inspect`, make sure you have `localhost:9222` and `localhost:9229` as options

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Thatkookooguy 's answer:

## Run electron with the `--inspect` and `--remote-debugging-port` flags

You can also just [run electron with the `inspect` flag](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process#command-line-switches), which allows you to debug your server code and has its own network tab with the "server-side" HTTP requests.

In order to see it, run your electron application like so:

```
electron --inspect=<portA> --remote-debugging-port=<portB> your/app
```

or

```sh
/Applications/My.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo --inspect=<portA> --remote-debugging-port=<portB>
```

if you want to immediatly break on the first line, run the same command but replace `--inspect` with `--inspect-brk`.

After running the command, open any web-browser and go to `chrome://inspect` and selecting to inspect the launched Electron app present there. [image]

hope this helped. If you have any questions, you can ask me in the comments

P.S if you want even more details you can run it like

```sh
/Applications/Mattermost.app/Contents/MacOS/Mattermost --no-sandbox --enable-logging --inspect --remote-debugging-port=9222
```