# Network Tab Node Inspect Chrome DevTools

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a version of NodeJS that supports viewing network activity in the network tab of Chrome DevTools? There is no network tab when I open DevTools using `node --inspect` or, `node --inspect-brk` in NodeJS v12.13.0.

Comment: please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873332/how-to-monitor-the-network-on-node-js-similar-to-chrome-firefox-developer-tools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to monitor the network on node.js similar to chrome/firefox developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873332/how-to-monitor-the-network-on-node-js-similar-to-chrome-firefox-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

If it's the network activity that you are after, then you could also potentially use the [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) library. It's good for doing any browser related things on the server. It opens up a headless (or non-headless) chromium instance and allows you to do a bunch of things. One of those things is to capture the network requests. [These posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969381/how-can-i-capture-all-network-requests-and-full-response-data-when-loading-a-pag) seem to talk a bit about that.